# How do I get the available wifi APs in Windows phone 8.1using c#

Tags: wifi, windows-8.1

Is there any way to getall WiFi access points and their respective RSSI values in windows 8.1 using .NET? It is simply working in windows 10 using Windows.Devices.WiFi.

Comment: No. It is windows 8.1 phone app

Answer (score 0):

Finally I realized that unfortunately there is no API for this in windows 8. However in windows 10 it can be achieved using Windows.Devices.Wifi